# Pull a process log of EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a few python files set up in a linux EC2 that run via cron. The output of the file gets stored in a database thats connected to a BI tool. I know for a fact a problem is occurring because I have missing data in my BI tool. Is there a command I can run or way to view error logs or run history so  I can see what's going on? Basically the equivalent of a console in Spyder.

PS. Both the EC2 and database instance turn on/off.

Comment: ssh into the instance and check your app logs.

Comment: Hey Marcin, not very familiar with app logs. In the var/log I found amazon, audit, boot, chrony, cloud-init, cloud-init-output, dmesg, journal, lastlog, maillog, sa, secure, spooler, wtmp, yum... any idea where to start?

Comment: Only you can know. Its your app. I don't know where it stores its log, assuming it actually makes any.

Comment: Gotcha. Not my app, just doing some troubleshooting. Thanks for the help. At least have a place to start

Comment: By default cron sends output the running user's email. Check /var/spool/mail as well.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks alot jordanm! Exactly what I was looking for.